# Excell : how many times a value OR another value appear in a column

Tags: excel

I have a column on Excel, I found out how to count how many times a value appears in it (ex: how many 1 in the column), but I can't find how to make it count how many times one OR another value appears in this column (ex: how many cells with the value 1 OR 2).
Here is an example of my colum:

A1  1;

A2  1;2;

A3  1;3;

A4  2;

A5  1;

A6  2;3;

A7  1;2;

- In this column, if I want to find how many cells with the number 1 there are, I would do : 
  =COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*1*")       and then the result would be : 5
- But if I want to find how many cells have the number 1 OR the number 2, I can't find how to do, but I know the result is 7 (because the all of these cells have or the number 1, or the number 2)
  The only way I found is to calculate the number of cells with the number 1 wich don't have the number 2, and to calculate the number of cells with the number 2 wich don't have the number 1, and add the sum of those to the number of cells with the value "*1;2*", wich gives me a long formula like: 
  =(COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*1*")-COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"*1*",A1:A7,"*2*"))+(COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*2*")-COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"*2*",A1:A7,"*1*"))+COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*1;2*")

Any one has a simpler formula?
Thank you so much if someone can resolve this!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your formula, this part, for example

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A7,"1",A1:A7,"2")`

...can only ever return 0 because `COUNTIFS` works on an "AND" basis and no cell can be both = 1 and = 2 at the same time

and if the data is exactly as shown with semi colons then surely this formula

`=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"1")`

will return zero too because none of your cell values are exactly 1

Are you over-simplifying your data for your question? I don't see how that formula will give you a result of 7

Try this formula to count how many cells contain either 1 or 2 (or both)

`=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(FIND(1,A1:A7))+ISNUMBER(FIND(2,A1:A7))>0)+0)`

...of course it will also count a cell if it contains 22 or 11, do you want it to do so in that case?

Comment: I meant each of my "1" or "2" were in fact " * 1 * " and " * 2 * "... anyways, THANKS ALOT for your formula, it worked!!!

Comment: Next question, do you have a formula if i wanna find in this column how many cells contain the number 1 AND the number 2? Thanks

Comment: You can adjust the `SUMPRODUCT` formula like this for an AND `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(1,A1:A7))*ISNUMBER(FIND(2,A1:A7)))`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a vba function and reference it.

something like

```
Function MyOrTest(cell)
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, 1) Or InStr(1, cell.Value, 2) Then
        MyOrTest = 1
    Else
        MyOrTest = 0
    End If
End Function
```

You will need to add it to a new Module in VBA.  Using this will allow just a normal sum function.

Comment: VBA (Visula Basic for Applications) is the macro language of Excel.  if you press `ALT-F11` it will bring up the VBA Editor.  Do a right click on **VBAProject(Book1)** and `Insert -> Module`